# How Do I Restore Chrome Previous Session Tabs from Command Line/Target Textbox in Chrome Properties?

Tags: google-chrome, restore, tabs

I've tried doing this, and when i open properties for google chrome:

the **target** box says:   "C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

the **start in** box says:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"

So If I type in the **target** box:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --restore-last-session"

And press Ok 
a Error shows up with the title 'problem with shortcut' saying 'The name 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --restore-last-session' specified in the target box is not valid. Make sure that the path and the filename are correct'

Is there a solution to this so i could reopen the tabs and windows that were closed when my laptop crashed?

Really quite worried about losing any tabs and getting behind on work - I've created a back up on a USB for the default folder in the user data folder.

What happened was that my laptop crashed and i reopened chrome but missed the restore button and there was no way to reopen the tabs - I then closed chrome and made sure not to reopen it in case i lost any data and made a back up.

When I saw this method being explained on this website: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/3018/google_chrome_force_restore_previous_session_command_line/

^For windows XP this website used in the **target** box- C:\Documents and Settings\Application Data\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --restore-last-session (If I use this in the **target** box then the error still appears)

Q)How could I do this for my Laptop? What would I have to type in the **command line/target box** so the error doesn't appear and I can restore what was lost?

Advice appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I think your quotations are in the wrong spot.
Try this: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --restore-last-session

Comment: This does not open all windows

Answer (score 0):

in PowerShell you can simply use

```
start chrome --restore-last-session
```